# Wrong default syntax highlighting in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I can't remember touching any related configuration, and for no reason, Sublime chooses "LaTeX Log" highlighting syntax as default for *.html files. I opened the Syntax Specific settings file and it's empty (?)

What can I do in order to get the proper highlighting for html files automatically?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Changing the syntax highlighting for any file type is easy in Sublime. Simply open a file with the extension you want to change, then click on **`View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as...`** and choose whichever language you wish. This will add the current extension to the `"extensions"` list in `Packages/User/LanguageName.sublime-settings`, where *`LanguageName`* is the syntax you chose, such as `HTML` in this case.