# How can I persist syntax highlighting settings in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

For many files or file types, such as .sh files, I have noticed that the syntax highlighting settings only lasts while you have that file open, when you re-open the file, you have to set the syntax again. Is there a way for Sublime to remember the syntax settings for each file?

Comment: I don't think this should be a duplicate since the question is not the same at all... (although answer is the same).

Comment: i think a more appropriate duplicate would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608006/wrong-default-syntax-highlighting-in-sublime-text-3

Answer (score 7):

Yes `view > syntax > Open all with current extension as...`

This will keep the chosen syntax highlight for all files with same extension.